# XPath - extract attribute

Tags: r, xpath

How do I extract the href attribute from this code using XPath?

```
<a 
itemprop="url" 
name="1055782959" 
href=“abc123”>
<span itemprop="name">myName</span>
</a>
```

EDIT:
A bit more details on what I'm trying to do.
I actually want to scape some data off a website using R.
I've tried the following,but it's not working:

```
xpathSApply(doc,"a/@href",xmlValue)
```

doc is the HTML page.

EDIT:
code to get the webpage:

```
fileUrl <- "http://www.gumtree.com.au/s-cars-vans-utes/toyota/page-1/k0c18320"
#doc <- htmlTreeParse(fileUrl, useInternal=T)

getLinks <- function() { 
  links <- character() 
  list(a = function(node, ...) { 
    links <<- c(links, xmlGetAttr(node, "href"))
    node 
  }, 
  links = function()links)
}

h1 <- getLinks
doc <- htmlTreeParse(fileUrl, useInternal = TRUE, handlers = h1); 
h1$links()
```

Comment: `xpathSApply(xmlInternalTreeParse(doc),"//a",xmlGetAttr,"href")`

Comment: @thelatemail This one gives me an error: Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'externalptr' to vector of type 'character'. But this code seems to worked a bit. It gives me all the URLs: xpathSApply(doc,"//a",xmlGetAttr,"href").

Comment: @user2343837 - I was taking `doc` to be the raw character data from the html. If you have already imported it as an XML object to R, then you don't need the Parse-ing.

Answer (score 2):

I like `getLinks` for getting `href` links.

```
> library(XML)
> txt <- '<a 
 itemprop="url" 
 name="1055782959" 
 href="abc123">
     <span itemprop="name">myName</span>
     </a>'     
> h1 <- getLinks()
> htmlParse(txt, asText = TRUE, handlers = h1)
> h1$links()
[1] "abc123"
```

If you already have an html document, `doc`, use `htmlParse(doc, handlers = h1)` in place of the `htmlParse` call above.  The `getLinks` function is found in the examples of `?htmlParse` and can be adusted for getting other attributes.

```
getLinks <- function() { 
        links <- character() 
        list(a = function(node, ...) { 
                    links <<- c(links, xmlGetAttr(node, "href"))
                    node 
                 }, 
             links = function()links)
}
```

Comment: I get an error: Error in handlers[w] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Probably because you have an html doc already.  Try it with  `htmlParse(doc, handlers = h1)`

Comment: I get another error:Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'externalptr' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: In your post, please provide the code used to get your `doc` so we can reproduce your real document.

Comment: @user2343837 -  Then it's `doc <- htmlTreeParse(fileUrl, useInternal = TRUE, handlers = h1); h1$links()`

Comment: I've added more code that I've used. I still get an error: `Error in handlers[w] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`, when I run the htmlTreeParse() function.

Comment: I'm not really sure what's happening.  It's working fine on my end. Have you tried running it in a fresh R session?